# Call Using GSM modem

Tags: vb.net, modem, gsm

I am developing Sms Project in vb.net.I can Send and receive Sms Easily. I can  attented Incoming call and dial. but not hearing and talk. I connected with com Port. This is possible or not for talking and hearing. please tell me

Comment: I would expect that a COM port does not transport voice.

Answer (score 1):

initiate dial/connect/send data sms are on **digital** connection, hence serial ports, talking on the other hand deals with voice, which is **analog** (unless converting analog to digital and send thru digital form - VoIP), you need to be able to connect to speaker and mike.
I would suggest to use http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoGSMShield --> easy to use and support all sms (digital) and voice (analog).
However, the application to initiate the work can be using VB.net

hope this help.